# Crop then stretch background image to fit an area

Tags: html, css, crop, fill, stretch

I have a 800 pixel wide, 500 pixel tall image and I am looking to first crop approx. x pix off the left side, y pix off the right side, z pix off the bottom, then fit it to a 1200 pixel wide, 1000 pixel tall background area, where x, y, and z are all different.

I also am trying to make it nonresponsive, so that it will not scale with changing the window size, so setting `background-size = cover` or `contain` is not an option. Any advice would be appreciated, such as if I can first crop the image, then simply fill it to my area. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you can use `background-position` to get the desired effect. And you understand that this will make the image stretch out of proportion, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pull this off without some tricky javascript. But I put it into code here so it will be easier for others to take a look - a good thing to do when you're posing the initial question too.

As-is, this uses background-position-x and -y to 'crop' off parts of the image, and then if there's a way to zoom in enough you can get your other ends cropped too, I'd imagine.

```css
.container {
border: solid black 1px;
height: 1000px;
width: 1200px;
background-image: url(https://snag.gy/dL487F.jpg);
background-position-x: -100px;
background-position-y: -50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `background-size` combined with percentage and pixel value to obtain what you want:

```css
.container {
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069);
  background-size:
    calc(100% + 100px + 200px) /*100% + x + y*/
    calc(100% + 50px); /*100% + z*/
  background-position:-100px 0; /*we shift by x*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  width:1200px;
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

You can also add CSS variable to easily control this:

```css
.container {
  --x: 100px;
  --y: 200px;
  --z: 50px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069);
  background-size: calc(100% + var(--x) + var(--y)) calc(100% + var(--z));
  background-position: calc(-1 * var(--x)) 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```